# PHP Change one frame from another

Tags: php, html, frame, gd, gd2

I have code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Электрическая схема</title>
 </head>
   <frameset rows="50%,50%">
   <frame src="input_data.php">
   <frame src="image_data.php">
   </frameset>
</html>
```

I have some fields and a button in "input_data.php".
And I have some variables in "image_data.php".
So, I want to when I change fields and clicking button, it changes variables and reloads second frame.

It looks like:
[image]

Comment: Please insert the 2 PHP codes.

Comment: Their codes is simple:
https://pastebin.com/vYhTTuVT
https://pastebin.com/42BsrcJS